# pass string from angular to .NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I need to send a variable from angular to .net core without needing to register it in the databse because i just need it for just one time.

this is my example from angular side(a test example)

```
value:string = "test";
self.http.get("http://localhost:5000/api/UserCode?code="+this.value)
          .subscribe(data=>{
            console.log(data);
            // console.log(this.value)
          })
      });
```

Backend(something like this)

```
 // GET: api/UserCode
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserCode()
        {
            return Ok(UserCodes);
        }
```

I think this is right but backend side i tried so many solutions but no result
So how to receive or read the value in the backend(.Net Core) without saving it and do i need a model or request params or what!!!
Thanks

Comment: Please, show your backend request handler. The question regards to backend, but no code is provided - I can't help, not enough information...

Comment: i have added the backend thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add parameter to your backend handler method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserCode(string code)
{
    // ...do whatever you want with code parameter here...
    return Ok(UserCodes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cant make this work is because you specify the parameter in the url and not in the body. Also it's a good idea to always use [FromBody] annotation and generally pass data that way.

That being said since you pass the variable from the url all you need is to specify the parameter in the function parameters.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserCode(string code)
```

And change the url to:

```
value:string = "test";
self.http.get("http://localhost:5000/api/UserCode/"+this.value)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        // console.log(this.value)
      })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you miss the `=` operatpr

```
UserCode?code="+this.value
```

Comment: i have the = operator i just forgot to write it in the snippet my problem is backend side thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the urlparameters.

```
value:string = "test";
const optionsParams = {
          params: new HttpParams()
            .set('code', this.value)
        };
self.http.get("http://localhost:5000/api/UserCode", optionsParams )
          .subscribe(data=>{
            console.log(data);
          })
      });
```

you also need to adjust service on the server

Comment: i'm asking for too much but can you help server side and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[FromQuery]` for [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes)

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserCode([FromQuery]string code)
```